# Angular FormGroup inside a FormArray is omitting a specific key

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formbuilder, formarray

I'm working in an Angular 8 web app.

I have a FormGroup that contains some controls and a key called `params` which is a FormArray. That FormArray contains FormGroups.

The problem is that I create these FormGroups (params) with a js object and they are losing the key `name`. Its very weird.

I'll posting the usefull code:

Here I create a preloaded form with the data from the backend:

```
public buildPreLoadedForm() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      ...this.currentFormula,
      params: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      formulaResult: []
  });

  this.updateFormulaParams();
}

public updateFormulaParams() {
  for (const param of this.currentFormula.params) {
    this.formParams.push(this.createFormulaParam(param));
  }
}

public createFormulaParam(formulaParam: FormulaParam) {
  return this.formBuilder.group({...formulaParam});
}
```

A param inside the "currentFormula" is like that:

```
 const param: FormulaParam = {
   ID: 0,
   CreatedAt: null,
   UpdatedAt: null,
   DeletedAt: null,
   name: 'val' + num,
   type: 'number'
 };
```

I'm pushing new params inside the form, doing that:

```
(this.form.get('params') as FormArray).push(this.createFormulaParam(param));
```

The param that I create, looks like:

[image]

But, inside the form (after pushing it), I get that:

[image: param object just created]

I'm loosing the `name` property! And it doesn't make sense for me.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd try renaming the variable to something else to see if it still disappears. Might be a reserved keyword somewhere along the processing line.

Comment: I just tried that, but it keeps doing the same. It's weird because I'm merging the object, not assigning the keys manually inside the form group. And the other keys are being assigned properly.

Comment: @IvanLencina Could you create a stackblitz working example along with HTML template..